# Is there any way for execute a stored procedure from an Oracle database?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a connection to an Oracle database, but I don't know how execute a stored procedure. Is it possible from Data Factory?

Answer (score 1):

I used a Lookup Activity and a SELECT statement of DUAL TABLE. Due to the stored procedures can not be call from a statement SELECT. I created an oracle function and the function calls the stored procedure. The function returns a value and this value is received by the lookup activity.
When you define the function, you have to add the statement PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION. This is because Oracle does not allow to execute DML instructions with a SELECT statement by default. Then, you need to define that DML instructions in the Stored Procedure will be an autonomous transaction.

```
--Tabla
CREATE TABLE empleados(
   emp_id NUMBER(9),
   nombre VARCHAR2(100),
   CONSTRAINT empleados_pk PRIMARY KEY(emp_id),
);

create or replace procedure insert_empleado (numero in NUMBER, nombre in VARCHAR2) is
 begin
    INSERT INTO empleados (emp_id, nombre)
    Values(numero, nombre);
COMMIT;
end;

create or replace function funcinsert_empleado (numero in NUMBER, nombre in VARCHAR2)
return VARCHAR2 
is
PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
begin
  insert_empleado (numero, nombre);
  return 'done';
end;
--statement in query of lookup
SELECT  funcinsert_empleado ('1', 'Roger Federer') 
FROM DUAL;
```

[Example lookup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K1qPC.png)

This is example in Spanish. https://dev.to/maritzag/ejecutar-un-stored-procedure-de-oracle-desde-data-factory-2jcp

Answer (score 0):

ADF currently only support stored procedure for azure SQL and SQL server.

Maybe you could consider custom activity. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-using-dotnet-custom-activity

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using a Lookup Activity, and where there is a choice of using a table or query, select query.  Since this provides a place to write your own statement, you can try writing an execute stored proc statement.

One thing to remember about Lookup activity, is it expects data to be returned.  If your stored proc does not return data, you may need to add an additional statement to return dummy data.

I have only done this with SQL before, but I see no reason it wouldn't work with Oracle as well.

[image]